# Making my List.filter faster on Scala?

Tags: performance, list, scala, filter

I'm making a game with Scala.

My game has several pools for keeping enemies. They are immutable Lists because they are initialized to a size that should be enough (because creating new enemy instances during the game is very expensive).

My game knows if an enemy is alive by asking `enemy.isVisible`. So my CollisionHandler works like:

1. Combine all live enemies to a list
2. Get live bullets
3. Space partition these and do collision detection for bullets and enemies in the same space partition

What supprised me was that according to the profiler, step 1 takes most of the time. And what that step does is basically say:

```
def allActiveEnemies = List(enemyType1.getAllActive, enemyType2.getAllActive, ... ).flatten
```

the `flatten` there doesn't seem expensive but instead it's get getAllActive calls. They are implemented in my Pooled trait like this:

```
trait Pooled[T <: Entity] {
    var pool = List[T]()
    val INITIAL_POOL_SIZE:Int

    def initPool() {
        for(i<-1 to INITIAL_POOL_SIZE)
        {
            addToPool(disable(createNew))
        }
    }

    def getAllActive:List[T] = pool.filter(e => e.isVisible)
}
```

(I omitted most of the trait because I don't think it's relevant here.)

pool.filter is what burns like 45% of the total time spent in CollisionHandler, which seems really strange.

Any suggestions to make things faster here?

Maybe using ArrayLists instead of List? Maybe using some sorting and mutable collections? Or am I simply doing something horribly wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: is `e.isVisible` a field access or a computation?

Comment: isVisible is a getter for a field (as I'm using a Java based game engine as the basis of my game).

Comment: I should probably add that I'm using Scala 2.8.1 and the game is run on Android 2.x

Comment: Scala's `List` has nothing to do with Java's `ArrayList`. Try a `Buffer` if you need to resize or a simple `Array` if you don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How large are these pools?  You do know that every time you make a list, you have to create a new object to hold each entry.  You could cut down on this a little by using a view on the filter (i.e. `pool.view.filter(e => e.isVisible)`; then return `Seq[T]`).  Generally, I think your strategy should be to not do extra filtering work each time.  Keep track of your active enemies in a `Set` or something; then you have them when you need them.

Comment: The pools are currently around 40 and there's like 5 of them. But both numbers will grow as we progress in our game, so a guess would be pool size around 100 and 10-15 pools.

Comment: @vertti - That shouldn't take any noticeable time at all--maybe a millisecond or two at the very worst.

Comment: Android profiler says around 27msec for CollisionHandler, half of that for the getActive filtters. :( That's already enough to impact frame rates considerably.

Comment: Ahhhh, Android.  You should have mentioned that initially.  You should try to make `allActiveEnemies` a set.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try that. Is there a specific reason Android prefers sets over lists?

Comment: @vertti - No, it's just that you're performance-limited.  A set lookup is constant time, and that constant is _much_ smaller than the constant time lookup to scan through a few hundred objects, making copies of new collections as you go.

Comment: Keeping track of active enemies with a Set was the best solution.